# Execv not working when using bin/time

Tags: c, fork, exec, execv

I have a problem in my program when i try to execute the `/bin/time /bin/echo Hello world`, I get no output. I know that this sample code works
for example with /bin/date or /bin/echo and i think it should also work with time but its not

```
int main(int argc, char * argv []) {    
    int err = 1;
    char *array[3] = {"/bin/time", "/bin/echo", "Hello World"};
    pid_t childPIorZero = fork();

    if (childPIorZero < 0){
        perror("fork() error");
        exit(-1);                        
    }
    if (childPIorZero != 0){
        printf("I'm the parent %d, my child %d\n",getpid(),childPIorZero);
        wait(NULL); 
    }           
    else{
         printf("I'm the child %d, my parent %d\n",getpid(), getppid());
         err = execv(array[0], array);
         printf("error = %d\n", err);
         printf("%s\n", strerror(err));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I though the problem was that i was passing in a wrong way the params to the execv, but it worked for the echo bin and the date bin so I don't knwo what is wrong. The output is the following:

```
I'm the parent 28001, my child 28011
I'm the child 28011, my parent 28001
error = -1
Unknown error -1
```

Comment: You need a null pointer at the end of `array`: `char *array[] = { "/bin/time", "/bin/echo", "Hello World", 0 };`.  Otherwise, `execv()` doesn't know when the argument list finishes — or it finishes when it comes across a null pointer, which may not be for a while and goodness only knows what garbage you get echoed.

Comment: However, that's not necessarily your immediate problem.  Are you sure you have a `/bin/time` as opposed to perhaps `/usr/bin/time`?  There's no merit in capturing the return value from `execv()`; if it returns, it failed.  The value to be passed to `strerror()` should be `errno`; it is not the return status from `execv()` since all error numbers are positive.  It's also a good idea to exit with a non-zero (failure) status if `execv()` fails.  And error messages should be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler I tried finishing with null but it didn't work, as i said i already tried using `/bin/echo` and it worked so i thought it should work. I also tried changing the path to `/usr/bin/time` but it didnt work either

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler I managed to make it work but i don't know why I have to specify the dir of time like this `/usr/bin/time/` and the one for echo only works if i write it like this `/bin/echo`, if i do `/usr/bin/echo` i get an error.
And it is strange because i went to the dir /bin/ and executed echo and it worked, but after that i did `ls`  and  I couldnt find echo in the dir list, is that an issue of my OS?

Comment: I have no ready explanation for the trailing slash on `time`.  If you have `/bin/echo`, you probably don't have `/usr/bin/echo` (though since one of `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is a symlink to the other on Solaris, you probably aren't running there, but if you are, you don't have that problem).  The `echo` command is a shell built-in but also a separate executable. Which platform are you on?  On macOS Sierra, there's `/usr/bin/time` but not `/bin/time`.  Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) seems to be the same way.  Try dropping that trailing slash.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code ran OK for me on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM hosted on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (and also ran OK on macOS, too).

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *array[] = { "/usr/bin/time", "/bin/echo", "Hello World", 0 };
    pid_t childPIorZero = fork();

    if (childPIorZero < 0)
    {
        perror("fork() error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (childPIorZero != 0)
    {
        printf("I'm the parent %d, my child %d\n", getpid(), childPIorZero);
        int status;
        int corpse;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1)
            printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I'm the child %d, my parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        execv(array[0], array);
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d) %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Key changes from the code in the question include:

- Changing location of `time` executable.
- Adding null pointer to the end of the `array`.
- Reporting errors on `stderr`, not `stdout`, after the `execv()` fails.
- Reporting the error from `errno`, not the return value from `execv()`, which is always `-1` if it returns at all.
- Exiting with an error status if the `execv()` fails.
- Looping until there are no children left (under funny circumstances, a process can inherit children that a previous incarnation of the same process forked off — mostly, you don't have to worry about it, but I always use a loop for waiting).
- Report the exit status for the child.

On Ubuntu, I compiled with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition ev11.c -o ev11
$ ./ev11
I'm the parent 25129, my child 25130
I'm the child 25130, my parent 25129
Hello World
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1620maxresident)k
8inputs+0outputs (1major+66minor)pagefaults 0swaps
PID 25130 exited with status 0x0000
$
```

I used the same compiling command line (but a different compiler, of course) on macOS and got:

```
$ ./ev11
I'm the parent 3220, my child 3221
I'm the child 3221, my parent 3220
Hello World
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
PID 3221 exited with status 0x0000
$
```